# Let D be an integral domain with characteristic 3. If x,y are elements of D then (x+y)^3 = x^3 +y^3

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am studying for an exam and the question is:

Prove: Let D be an integral domain with characteristic $3$. If $x$ and $y$ are elements of $D$, then $(x+y)^3 = x^3 + y^3$.

Comment: Hint: Expand $(x + y)^3$.

Comment: $(x+y)^3=x^3+3x^2y+3xy^2+y^3.$ What can you deduce from this?

Comment: I am stuck at (x+y)^3 = x^3 + y^3 + 3yx^2 + 3xy^2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$ (x+y)^3 = x^3 + \binom {3}{1}x^2y+\binom{3}{2}xy^2 + y^3$$ And notice that $ 3|\binom {3}{1}$ and $3| \binom{3}{2}$.

More generally, if D is a domain of characteristic $p > 0$ and $q = p^{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}$, then for all $x,y \in D$ you have that $$(x+y)^q = x^q+y^q$$

This is sometimes called the [freshman's dream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman's_dream).

Answer (score 1):

$(x+y)^3=x^3+y^3+3x^2y+3xy^2$ because the char(D)=3 then $3x^2y=3xy^2=0$